# How to capture exception in django rest framework with django middleware?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-middleware

Django middleware have a `process_exception` hook which can be used to capture exception and handler.

But there is some  problem while using Django restframe work

```
class ExceptionHandler(MiddlewareMixin):

    @staticmethod
    def process_exception(request, exception):

        if isinstance(exception, ValidationError):
            return Response(data=exception.messages, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

For example, I try to use above middleware to capture the `ValidationError` and return HTTP 400

But it will not work and raise below error

```
AssertionError: .accepted_renderer not set on Response
```

It turns out that the rest-framework view layer will add a `.accepted_renderer` to  the  response.

If I handle the exception outside view. This attribute will be  missed and cause another exception.

So my question is: Is it wrong to handle exception  in middleware when using django rest-framework?

What is the correct way to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to do this in Django Rest framework is to create a custom exception handler and replace the default exception handler with your custom handler. For more details on it you can check out the official documentation: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling